# Dynamically loop through a text file and get common matches

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a script that outputs data to a text file.  Now I need a way of getting a count of the lines that match the project and gets a count.  I know how to get the count of one value by doing

```
$ProjectMatches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "PROJECT ID FOAH834" -AllMatches
```

But I need to loop through the text file and get a count for each `PROJECT ID SOMEPROJECTNUMBER` and get a count of each and export those results to a csv file.  My goal is to show how much time was dedicated to each project.  Each entry being 15 minutes of time.

```
11/2/2017 8:07:34 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH834
11/2/2017 8:07:36 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH834
11/2/2017 8:07:38 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH841
11/2/2017 8:10:15 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH18
11/2/2017 8:10:17 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH690
11/2/2017 8:10:21 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID PRJ0036909
11/2/2017 8:19:32 PM
This 15 minutes is dedicated to PROJECT ID FOAH18
11/2/2017 8:21:02 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do some regex matching then string manipulation rather then hard coding all the values

I would use something like

```
$matches = [regex]:matches($FileContent,"PROJECT ID .*<br/>")
```

to get all your project codes. Then loop over it, do some string manipulation and insert it into a hash table

```
$hashtable = @{}
foreach ($entry in $matches){
    $entry = $entry.replace(...)
    $projectcode = $entry.split(....)
    $hashtable[$projectcode] += 1
}
```

Then you can process the hashtable with something like

```
foreach($entry in $hashtable.keys){
    write-output "$entry: $($hashtable[$entry])"
}
```